# My Rails 3 + Ember + Ember Rails + Ember Data app to Heroku/AWS doesn't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, ember-data

This has been driving me nuts because I've tried ruling out a lot of different things this past week and here I am.

I have a Rails 3.2.13 app with these gems (only a subset shown here):

> gem 'asset_sync'
>
> gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.3.1'
>
> gem 'ember-data-source', "~> 1.0.0.beta.6"
>
> gem 'ember-rails'
>
> gem 'emblem-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/alexspeller/emblem-rails.git' (for templating)

Every time I deploy to Heroku and I try to access the ember app it never loads. I've checked to make sure it was the right Ember variant on production.rb as well.

Another fix that seemed to work in the past was to not override the ember-rails vendor files with a more latest version of ember-data (https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/264). I instead added ember-source and ember-data-source versions to the Gemfile. That seemed to fix the issue but still Heroku would hang on the network request to my ember application (looking at chrome network tab - it hangs up sometimes on the html and other times on the js file with the ember-app).

To rule out Heroku as an issue, I also tried deploying my app to AWS and would still get these issues sometimes.

To rule out Heroku's static asset serving as an issue, I also tried pushing my assets to S3 (using the asset_sync gem) and serving it from there and I'm still getting this issue where it would hang on the page. But eventually a bit after deployment it works sometimes but is incredibly slow when it does.

Other notable thing is the whole Ember app uses coffeescript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with Heroku not pre-compiling my assets and thus not loading the page.

This solved it:

```
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```